# How to draw a slice of piechart with an image file instead of filling with color in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, slice, pie-chart, mpandroidchart, graph-visualization

currently, I'm using MPAndroidChart library (v3.0.3) for developing an Android App that could visualize the user' steps in a Piechart. In our design, we want to draw a slice of the chart with an image instead of filling it with a specific color. I searched many posts but didn't find useful information.

Our UI design is as this image of the [piechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np5AJ.jpg). We want to draw the slice with an image of "dots patterns." as an indicator for encouraging the user to achieve the daily goal. Is it possible to do that with MPAndroidChart? If it's yes, could you give me some hints or references to try on? Thank you very much.

Comment: can you post the expect piechart?

Comment: Sorry, I am still collecting the reputations to be allowed to post the images in the question. At this moment, could you please check this image: http://reach.bitnamiapp.com/Asking_Helps/HT_dailyview_piechart.jpg. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. All you have to do is create two entries for pieChart. Give 1 entry the percentage you want to show and the other entry remaining percentage from hundred.Then set color of first entry to your required color and set color of seconentry as transparent. Also apply center text whatever you want to write in center.

Follow code below it will do the job:

```
    PieChart pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    ArrayList<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(66, "Today"));
    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(44, ""));

    PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries, "");
    pieDataSet.setColors(Color.BLUE,Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pieDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);

    pieChart.getDescription().setText("");
    pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pieChart.getDescription().setTextSize(12);
    pieChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
    pieChart.setCenterText("1600 Steps");
    pieChart.setCenterTextSize(22);
    pieChart.setCenterTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12);
    pieChart.animateY(1000);
    pieChart.setData(pieData);
```

[image]

Comment: Do let me know for further assistance. Happy Coding !

Comment: Hi M.Saad Lakhan, thank you very much. For the "transparent" slice, what we want is to apply an "image" on it (such as the dotted pattern on  http://reach.bitnamiapp.com/Asking_Helps/HT_dailyview_piechart.jpg). Do you know how to do that? Is it possible to draw it in the background? So that it could be seen through the "transparent" part. What do you think?

Comment: You need to design a drawable which you want to show and replace that transparent color with drawable. This is the way to do that.

Comment: I never did that but I think we can do this in that way let me check it I will get back to you soon.

Comment: I think thats not possible you have to use this transparent thing this is the nearest thing to your requirement or you can set very light gray color.

Comment: Have you implemented this ?